# Get handle to process for a Metro app

Tags: c++, process, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

From a desktop app, I start a metro app using [ActivateApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx) and  I would like to turn the out parameter process id into a process handle so I can use [WaitForSingleObjectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) or [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683189.aspx). I saw that [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms684320.aspx) should do exactly what I am looking for, but it doesn't work. The returned handle is always null. I am guessing one of two possibilities:

1. The started app is a metro app and not a desktop app and that is why I am not allowed to get a handle to its process.
2. The access rights I request in OpenProcess are not approved by the app's process. Which access right could I use to make sure it's not this ? I am looking for an access right anyone can use. Is there such a thing? If not, is there a way I could control the access rights from the ActivateApplication call?

Comment: You need to write this off, it is only useful to a debugger.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're referring to. What should I "write off" ?

Comment: I consider it a valid question. All process-related methods require process handles but you are only offered process Ids. There should be a way of turning one into the other and when it doesn't work, we should be able to tell why and how to fix it.

Comment: What error code is returned?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this, looping through the windows and comparing the process id to find the right handle.

```
HWND GetProcessWindow( DWORD processId )
{
// Now need to run a loop to get the correct window for process.
bool bFound = false;
HWND prevWindow = 0;

while ( ! bFound ) {
    HWND desktopWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
    if ( ! desktopWindow )
        break;

    HWND nextWindow = FindWindowEx( desktopWindow, prevWindow, NULL, NULL );
    if ( ! nextWindow )
        break;

    // Check whether window belongs to the correct process.
    DWORD procId = -1;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( nextWindow, &procId );

    if ( procId == processId ) {
        // Add additional checks. In my case, I had to bring the window to front so these checks were necessary.
        wchar_t windowText[ 1024 ];
        if ( IsWindowVisible( nextWindow ) && ! IsIconic( nextWindow ) && GetWindowText( nextWindow, ( LPWSTR )windowText, sizeof( windowText ) / sizeof( wchar_t ) )
            && ! GetParent( nextWindow ) )
            return nextWindow;
    }

    prevWindow = nextWindow;
}

return 0;
```

}

ref :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/7e25e104-36cb-41ac-8f36-0e4c6b6146a3/finding-hwnd-of-metro-app-using-win32-api